# How can I structure an ASP.NET MVC application with a "Core" database and individual derived databases using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I had a hard time naming and wording this question, as there's a lot to unpack, so I apologize in advance - for anyone who spends the time to review and respond to this, I very much appreciate you.

---

**Background:**

I have a relatively large ASP.NET MVC5 application using Entity Framework 6, using a SQL Server database. Currently, the solution is split in to a few projects, mostly split by layer (business, data, etc). There is a single .edmx file and dbContext for the application, and it points to a single database at the moment.

The code/solution above represents the "core" of the system being built. However, this application is customized per client, therefore each client could have their own modules, pages, logic, etc. Due to this, we have a project in the solution for each client (only a couple right now, but will eventually be 50+ - is that an issue? Split the solution up maybe?). The intention is to be able to deploy just that client's code along with the core, or to be able to deploy just the core as well.

In addition to the custom modules in the code, they may also have their own custom database, again derived from a Core database. The custom database will always be kept up to date with the core db, but may have additional objects (tables, stored procedures, etc). On thing to note, I do not have the option of veering away from this approach - each client will definitely have their own copy of the "core", but it will be kept up to date utilizing a push tool developed in-house.

---

**Problem/Question:**

With that, which will essentially be the Core database with the potential for extra objects added in for that client's implementation.

The issue I'm struggling with is how to implement this in Entity Framework in a way which does not require me to add all of those custom db objects to the Core database, or at the very least keep them logically separated, relegated to the client projects. What would be the best way to go about this?

---

**My Idea For Implementation**

This is definitely where I am struggling at the moment. I am not really sure if my current idea will work, but I am still investigating and trying to come up with better options.

My current idea is as follows... Since I can target a specific schema when generating an EDMX, place client specific objects in a schema for their project, and utilize those to generate a dbContext in each client project/database, which inherits from the Core's dbContext implementation (containing all the "core" objects). This would mean ClientA's project would have an edmx file with just their custom tables/objects, inheriting all of the core's objects, but keeping them separate from other client's objects.

I'm not completely certain whether this approach will work (playing with it now), my initial concerns are that Entity Framework doesn't appear to generate foreign keys between the contexts. For example, if ClientA's table has a foreign key pointing to a core table, the generation tool doesn't appear to generate that relationship. That said, could I manually implement this effectively? The core code is database first, however I could implement the smaller, client specific items code-first, which I believe would give me far more flexibility. Would this be an effective approach? If not, is there a better approach out there I could use?

Comment: Doing a custom database per customer is going to be hell. You can give each customer a different database, but have them all use the same design. My company has 7,000 databases this way. They used to be custom, and I hear horror stories about how bad it was.

Comment: The issue I have is that I don't necessarily have an option - each client's instance of this app is standalone - they have their own instance of the database, web server, etc. The core code remains the same and we deploy to all of those environments (and yes, it is a pain), but custom modules etc. need to be able to be pushed to the individual clients as well.

Comment: Yes, you do have an option. Stop doing custom database's per client. You can have separate instances without having them be custom. If you go the custom route, you're going to put yourself in a world of pain. Put all the functionality needed into the standard database, and have everyone use the standard database. Use feature toggles to control what functionality actually ends up getting used. Don't do a branch per customer - do a branch for a feature.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear - when I mentioned the lack of an option, I meant it more as a directive from management, as they didnt want unused entities in the db for any given client. That said, speaking with them this morning I was able to convince them that having an unused entity from client A's implementation in client B's database is better than having to manage them as individual dbs. So that simplified this quite a bit, I still have some things I need to clarify with them and may come back to SO later once this is a bit more clear.

Comment: Good job! Don't take everything management says for granted - they don't always know the costs associated with their decisions. If you can show them solid reasons why to go about things in another way, they'll often listen. My company has three different types of applications. We split each customer or facility into their own database. One application has 7,000 databases, another has 600, another has 70. We'd never be able to manage them all the way you were talking about doing.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @mason. Echoing our experience 100%. Management needs to know how expensive it is to manage custom databases and code bases. And they need to have it presented with hard evidence and in numbers they understand -> $$$. I.e. We have a team of 5 working on this project. Typically each member of team spends about 40% of their time just maintaining that nightmare of custom DBs and codebase. That is equivalent of 2 full-time developers, equivalent of $100K per year, just to remove some empty unused tables from client's databases.

Comment: Put it this way and see how soon you'll get an approval to redo the architecture into a more manageable structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a developer in very similar situation (6 years of project for multiple clients) I can say that your approach is full of pain. Customising your code per client is a road to hell.

You need to deploy the same code to every client. Core stays the same. Satellite modules developed for a specific client should be done as generic as possible (so you can re-sell them multiple times) and also deployed to everyone. The trick is to have a good toggle system that will enable only the right functionality per client.

I.e. there is a controller that saves for example company information. Everyone gets the same code, but if a customer BobTheBuilder Ltd. requires a special validation for companies, then that code goes into `MyApp.BobTheBuilder.*` namespace and your configuration code should know that this code should be executed instead of your general code. Needless to say that this should be done via DI container and implementations should be replaced by injecting objects that implement the common interface.

As for database - you can have multiple DB Contexts that represent your database modules. They can live in the same database, but best to separate modules by schema name. So yes, all those objects go to your codebase. Only not every tenant will get all the tables - only enabled modules should be activated and create their tenant tables.

As for project per customer - that's also is a big pain. Imagine if you have more than 10 customers and need to update `Newtonsoft.Json` package - that usually takes a bit more than forever! We tried that and fell back to namespace per customer overrides.

Generally here is our schema:

- Tenants all get the same codebase deployed to them, but functionality is disabled by toggles
- Tenants each get their own database with all the tables and enabled schemas(modules)
- Do not customise your core per tenant. All customisations go into modules.
- CQRS is recommended, but you can live without it. Though life is a lot easier when you have only a handful of interfaces to think about.
- DI is a must. Can't make all that happen without a good container that supports multi-tenancy.
- There are modules that do some specific stuff developed per customer. Each module has it's own toggles and very configurable - so multiple tenants can get the same module, but can be re-configured independently.

Comment: Thanks for the response - one thing to note is that this application wouldn't technically be multitenancy if I understand correctly. Each client must (by law in our case) have their own server instances etc.. So, if a new client comes on board, we need to deploy the core, then it is configured for them. If they have custom modules, those are built in the same solution but in a project for that client (so we can deploy just their code, just the core, or both) if that makes sense? You make some great points and I will respond in more detail shortly (dealing with some items at work atm)

Comment: Also, all clients will have the core database/system. The core is developed in it's own branch (so client development will never directly impact core), and each client has their own branch as well for any custom modules/development for them only. We just need to be able to do targeted deployments, and since they all have to have their own databases, it complicates things, even with the DBs being identical structure-wise (plus whatever is added for their implementation specifically)

Comment: I see where you are. That was a good time for us to dodge. We had a branch per customer at one point. After a certain amount of merges-gone-wrong you go crazy and loose a will to live. Targeted custom deployment pipeline is also something we have done - another pain we luckily left behind.

Comment: @CTDev and for the application to be multitenanted you don't have to have a single server per client. We had that as well - a server per client. That was OK, but deployments of new versions was still a pain. Though use of Octopus Deploy reduced that pain significantly. Yet every client had the same code deployed to them, only configured differently. And configuration was handled on deployment time by Octopus.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement inheritance with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

There are a few approaches *Table-Per-Hierarchy* (TPH) inheritance, *Table Per Type* (TPT) inheritance and *Table-per-Concrete Class* (TPC) inheritance.

You might also consider a Microservic-ie architecture if you're concerned how the different schema's will integrate.

> Entity Framework doesn't appear to generate foreign keys between the contexts.

That approach sounds painful. Using Microservices to encapsulate the Core and client dBs as their own entities you could then use Message Queue's to broker communication between them.